# Exception Handling + polymorphism, doesnt work if the exception method, doesnt work in the same class

Tags: c++, exception, polymorphism, virtual-functions, throw

I am trying some code like this

```
//A.hpp
 class A{
   public:
       A() {} 
       virtual const char *message() const {return "A ERROR";}
 };

 //B.hpp

 #include "A.hpp"

 class B:public A {
   public:
       B() {}
       const char *message() const {return "B ERROR";}
 };

//main.cpp
 #include "A.hpp"
 #include "B.hpp"

void foo(const A& a) {
   /* case 1 */ throw a;   /* (or) */ /* case 2 */ throw B(); // LINE 100
}

int main() {

  B b;
  A &a(b);
  b.message(); // OUTPUT: B ERROR

  try {
      foo(a);
  } catch (const A& a) {
     std::cout<<"EXCEPTION CALLED "<<a.message()<<std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

in this case, if I use 
case 1:
      throw a; //a is an reference of B b;
      OUTPUT: A ERROR

case 2:
     throw B(); // creates new B;
     OUTPUT: B ERROR

What I don't understand is, why doesn't there is no consistency betweek two cases,

If you pass by reference, all the time, there should be some consistency,
If I create a new variable inside the function, that is called in the try block, then it calls the correct virtual method, else it doesn't..... Can anyone tell me the control flow.... Please advise....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because an object is copied before thrown.

Even if the parameter `a` of `foo` points to an instance of `B` at run-time, what matters is the **compile-time** type of the throw expression. So, effectively, the instance of `B` is passed to the copy-constructor of `A` (which is legitimate since `B` inherits `A`) and a new `A` instance created and then thrown.

The reason for copy is that compiler must guarantee the lifetime of the exception object as long as there is any `catch` block that could catch it. So, it can't risk a stack object "falling off the stack edge" or heap object being deallocated by some destructor invoked during stack unwinding.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness I feel the need to point out that just like virtual copy (also known as cloning) solves copying through a base, virtual (re)throw solves throwing through a base:

```
struct base {
    virtual void
    rethrow() const
    { throw *this; }

    // it's also usual to make the base type abstract
    // so that users can't slice, e.g. boost::exception
    // it's also possible to make copying protected
};

struct derived: base {
    void
    rethrow() const override
    { throw *this; }
};

void
foo(base const& b)
{
    // no: slices
    // throw b;

    b.rethrow(); // Ok
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Throwing copies variables. Your `throw a` in foo doesn't actually throw the reference to `a` from main, it in fact throws a copy of `a`. In the catch statement, you're catching that copy by reference. Since in foo, `a` is a reference to an `A`, the copy slices the object, and it becomes an `A`, thus losing the fact that it ever was a `B`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm having a little trouble understanding exactly what you are asking but...
First, don't name the variable of your catch the same name as your local variable, that is you are using "a" twice to represent different things. You may be thinking that the item you catch by reference is the a you passed into foo and that will not be true if foo() throws B. Just for clarity change your catch to

```
catch (const A& ex)
{
 ...ex.message()...
}
```

I suspect what is happening is that when declared outside the try, **a** is still in scope and **a.message()** calls the local variable **a**. If declared inside the try, **a** is no longer in scope in the catch, so the **a** you are catching by reference calls its message. Changing the variable name of the catch should remove the seemingly ambiguous behavior.

Comment: whichever `a` is used there, neither should have displayed the observed message.

Comment: I couldn't tell from the question exactly what is thrown under what conditions. I just noticed in the last sentence that there is different behavior if a is declared inside the try or outside the try. Since there is **NO REASON** to reuse the variable name "a" like this, it seems only sensible to me to clean this up. Not sure why someone thinks that is a bad idea.

Comment: The downvote isn't because your advice is bad, (it's good advice) it's because this isn't the answer to the problem.